# How to divide world in regions of specific size?

Tags: netlogo, patch

I am having troubles building my model: I am trying to build an agricultural area, where a specific number of farmers have lands of different sizes (also specific, not random). In the farmers' proprieties, there are fields (yellow patches) and forest (green patches).

Here's a bit of code:

```
breed [Smallfarmers Smallfarmer] Smallfarmers-own [property]
breed [Mediumfarmers Mediumfarmer]
Mediumfarmers-own [property]

to setup
ca

loop [
repeat 50[
  create-Smallfarmers 1 [
    set property [patches in-radius-nowrap 1.5] of one-of patches with [pcolor = black]
  if all? (patch-set [neighbors] of property) [pcolor = black] [
    ask n-of 2 property [set pcolor green]
    ask property with [pcolor != green] [set pcolor yellow]]]] 
  
 repeat 10[
  create-Mediumfarmers 1 [
  set property [patches in-radius-nowrap 2.9] of one-of patches with [pcolor = black]
  if all? (patch-set [neighbors] of property) [pcolor = black] [
    ask n-of 6 property [set pcolor green]
    ask property with [pcolor != green] [set pcolor yellow]]]]
stop]
end
```

With this code I have these problems:

- not all the farmers are created.
- the properties are floating in the black space, far apart.

How can I improve (or completely revolutionize) my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several distinct issues with this. The first are general NetLogo bits:

1. Using `in-radius-nowrap` suggests to me that you have the world wrapping and don't really want it to wrap since it is land and it doesn't make sense to wrap. You can turn off wrapping with the settings button (top right) on the interface, where you also set the number of patches in the world.
2. If you want to create (say) 10 farmers, you don't need to do `repeat 10 [create-farmers 1 ...`, you just create 10 at once. All the code in the [ ] that sets up the property will happen for each farmer because it is part of the create block.
3. `neighbors` is already a patchset, but I suspect you want to include the central patch as well

Your specific problem about too few properties too far apart - In fact, all the farmers and their properties are being created but their properties are not being coloured. Your code creates a farmer and gives them property, but only colours it if the property does not overlap.

So to fix this, you need to create the farm only where there is space. It is probably easier to create the larger farms first, and then the smaller farms can fill in the gaps. Looking at your code though, all the farms are the same size (3x3) and the difference is how many fields are green or yellow. Here is some code that creates farms (notice also that it puts the farmer on the farm).

```
breed [farmers farmer]
farmers-own
[ property
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-farmers 10
  [ let potential-farms patches with [all? (patch-set self neighbors) [pcolor = black]]
    ifelse any? potential-farms
    [ move-to one-of potential-farms
      set property (patch-set patch-here neighbors)
      ask n-of 2 property [set pcolor green]
      ask property with [pcolor != green] [set pcolor yellow]
    ]
    [ print "No space available" ]
  ]
end
```